# duda abrir archivo.txt desde python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hola buenas soy nuevo aquí y me gustaría saber como abrir archivos en python. Estoy utilizando este codigo `f = open("nombre del archivo.txt")` pero me da error ¿por qué? gracias de antemano

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    f=open("text1.txt",'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text1.txt'
```

Comment: ¿Has leído el error? Suele ayudar... ;)

Comment: Hola, podrías poner el error para tratar de ayudarte

Comment: Si alguna de las respuesta te fue de ayuda seleccionala como aceptada :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que no estas apuntando a la ubicacion correcta del archivo. Velo de esta manera, suponiendo que tienes una carpeta `Mi Proyecto` con la siguiente estructura:

```
Mi_Proyecto
      |----- text1.txt
      |----- programa.py
```

El codigo que intentas usar funcionaria, pues el archivo `text1.txt` se encuentra en el mismo lugar que el archivo `programa.py`

Sin embargo en tu caso al parecer el archivo `text1.txt` se encuentra en otro lugar, diferente al archivo del programa que estas creando; por tanto debes modificar la ruta para que apunte al lugar adecuado.

Por ejemplo suponiendo que tu estructura sea asi:

```
Mi_Proyecto
      |----- programa.py
text1.txt
```

Entonces en tu programa podrias escribir:

```
f = open("../nombre del archivo.txt")
```

Los `../` en la ruta indican que quieres subir un nivel en el directorio, por tanto sales de la carpeta `Mi_Proyecto` y asi puedes encontrar el archivo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de mostrar datos del error para mayor información, para leer el archivo prueba de este modo:

`archivo=open("/ruta-del-archivo/nombre-archivo.extencion", 'r')`

Para leer las líneas:

`lineas = archivo.readlines()`.

La función `open()`, debe de recibir dos parámetros, el primero es el archivo, si dicho archivo no se encuentra al mismo nivel del script de python entonces debes especificar la ruta para llegar al archivo, el segundo parámetro es el modo de apertura del archivo q puede ser:

`'r'` : read/lectura.

`'w'` : write/escritura.

`'rb'` : read as binary/ leer archivo como binario.

`'U'` : es un formato especial que permite varias operaciones, estas son algunas, existen más.

Te sugiero que estudies acerca de este tema, espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Mi respuesta se actualizó después de pusiste datos del error, el problema es q el archivo q deseas abrir no está al mismo nivel del archivo .py debes especificar la ruta del archivo.